# JQuery show element which has an element with class in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have a drop down menu ul when I am on the page I would like to have the drop down menu stay so I want to show the ul item only if it has a li element with the class ".current-menu-item" in it. I found this code, but it would show all drop downs (.sub-menu) I only want to have the one with the ".current-menu-item" in it to be shown:

```
if ($(".sub-menu").find(".current-menu-item").length > 0){ 
$(".sub-menu").css('display', 'block');
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$(".sub-menu:has(.current-menu-item)").show();
```